# AFNetworking IPhone 7 Simulator

Tags: xcode, web-services, redirect, ios-simulator, afnetworking

I am facing the strange issue today, AFNetworking service call returns me strange response, is there anyone facing the same issue.

```
Error: Error Domain=com.alamofire.error.serialization.response Code=-1016 "Request failed: unacceptable content-type: text/html" UserInfo={com.alamofire.serialization.response.error.response=<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x600000428b80> { URL: http://www.duba.com/ } { status code: 200, headers {
"Accept-Ranges" = bytes;
Connection = "Keep-Alive";
"Content-Length" = 151;
"Content-Type" = "text/html";
Date = "Mon, 29 May 2017 07:16:55 GMT";
"Last-Modified" = "Fri, 17 Jul 2015 02:16:24 GMT";
"Proxy-Connection" = "Keep-Alive";
Server = "Kingsoft Web Server";
Via = "1.1 PROXY";} },
NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://www.duba.com/, com.alamofire.serialization.response.error.data=<3c68746d 6c3e0a3c 68656164 3e0a3c74 69746c65 3e57656c 636f6d65 20746f20 6e67696e 78213c2f 7469746c 653e0a3c 2f686561 643e0a3c 626f6479 20626763 6f6c6f72 3d227768 69746522 20746578 743d2262 6c61636b 223e0a3c 63656e74 65723e3c 68313e57 656c636f 6d652074 6f206e67 696e7821 3c2f6831 3e3c2f63 656e7465 723e0a3c 2f626f64 793e0a3c 2f68746d 6c3e0a>, NSLocalizedDescription=Request failed: unacceptable content-type: text/html}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found, the afnetworking was working on other iphone simulators but not working on iphone 7.